# AspNetCoreで作ったサーバーアプリケーションを外部のサーバで公開したい

Tags: c#, unity3d, network, http, asp.net-core

私は、Asp.Net.Coreを使い、サーバー用のアプリケーションを作りました。クライアント側はUnityで作ったソフトからそのサーバーにアクセスします。
ローカルの環境では正常に動作しましたが、外部のサーバーにアップロードして、サーバー上でサーバー用のアプリケーションを起動し、クライアント側からソフトを起動して、そのサーバーにアクセスしようとしましたが、アクセスできません。

Unity側のエラーコード

```
HttpRequestException: error trying to connect: tcp connect error: 接続済みの呼び出し先が一定の時間を過ぎても正しく応答しなかったため、接続できませんでした。または接続済みのホストが応答しなかったため、確立された接続は失敗しました。 (os error 10060)
```

Server側のログ

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
  Now listening on: http://(サーバーのIPアドレス):8080
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
  Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
  Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
  Content root path: /game
```

サーバーのProgram.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        builder.WebHost.UseUrls("http://160.251.138.42:8080");

        builder.WebHost.UseKestrel(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureEndpointDefaults(endpointOptions =>
            {
                endpointOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2;
            });
        });

        builder.Services.AddGrpc();
        builder.Services.AddMagicOnion();

        var app = builder.Build();

        app.MapMagicOnionService();

        app.Run();
    }
}
```

Unity側のアクセスに関する部分

```
    handler = new YetAnotherHttpHandler();
    handler.Http2Only = true;
    options = new GrpcChannelOptions { HttpHandler = handler, 
                               UnsafeUseInsecureChannelCallCredentials = false };
    channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://(サーバーのIPアドレス):8080", options);
```

どのようにしたら、クライアントからサーバーに接続できるようになりますか。

サーバー側のOS
CentOSStream9

Answer (score 2):

ローカルで実行できているのであれば、外部サーバー側の問題と考えられます。外部サーバー側の Firewall でポート 8080 は許可されていますか？
もしくは、クライアントからサーバーへのルートで、通信をブロックしている要因があるかもしれません。ネットワーク上のクライアントの配置場所を変えて、疎通が可能か確認してみると良いかもしれません。curl や Postman 等で、外部サーバーへの疎通を確認してみると、切り分けが明確になると思います。